# Can my code be optimized more?

Tags: jquery, optimization, css, html5

**Preview:** http://sparksonrails.pennfolio.com/

**Jquery:**

```
function introIconFirst()
{
    $('h2.ribbon').css(
    {
        'marginTop': '+30px',
        'opacity': '0'
    }).animate(
    {
        marginTop: '0',
        opacity: '1'
    }, 1500, 'easeOutElastic', introIconSecond());
}
function introIconSecond()
{
    $('#ico_website').rotate('0deg').css(
    {
        'top': '+900px',
        'opacity': '0'
    }).animate(
    {
        top: '50px',
        opacity: '1'
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 1100,
        easing: 'easeOutElastic'
    }).animate(
    {
        rotate: '-30deg'
    }, 1000, 'easeOutElastic', introIconThird());
}
function introIconThird()
{
    $('#ico_rails').css(
    {
        'top': '+900px',
        'opacity': '0'
    }).delay(300).animate(
    {
        top: '145px',
        opacity: '1'
    }, 1400, 'easeOutElastic', introIconFourth());
}
function introIconFourth()
{
    $('#ico_plane').css(
    {
        'left': '255px',
        'top': '90px',
        'opacity': '0'
    }).delay(800).animate(
    {
        top: '18px',
        left: '299px',
        opacity: '1'
    }, 600, 'linear');
}


// Rotate/Animate Stuff - Page2 Options

function rotPlane()
{ 
    $('li#blk-specialize span.elem2').animate(
    {
        rotate: '-=30deg'
    }, 300, 'linear');
}


function rotGear1() 
{ 
    $('li#blk-happen span.elem1').animate(
    {
        rotate: '+=30deg'
    }, 700, 'linear');
}


function rotGear2() 
{ 
    $('li#blk-happen span.elem2').animate(
    {
        rotate: '-=30deg'
    }, 400, 'linear');
}


//Globe plane
setInterval( rotPlane, 1 );


//Gear 1 - Large
setInterval( rotGear1, 1 );

//Gear 2 - Small
setInterval( rotGear2, 1 );




$(function() {

    introIconFirst(); 

    $(".options li").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).append('<span class="elem1"></span><span class="elem2"></span>');
      },
      function () {
        $(".options li span").detach();
      }
    );


    // Cache the Window object
    $window = $(window); 

    // Cache the Y offset and the speed of each sprite
    $('[data-type]').each(function()
    {
        $(this).data('offsetY', parseInt($(this).attr('data-offsetY')));
        $(this).data('Xposition', $(this).attr('data-Xposition'));
        $(this).data('speed', $(this).attr('data-speed'));
    }); // For each element that has a data-type attribute
    $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function()
    { // Store some variables based on where we are
        var $self = $(this),
            offsetCoords = $self.offset(),
            topOffset = offsetCoords.top; // When the window is scrolled...
        $(window).scroll(function()
        { // If this section is in view
            if (($window.scrollTop() + $window.height()) > (topOffset) && ((topOffset + $self.height()) > $window.scrollTop()))
            { // Scroll the background at var speed
                // the yPos is a negative value because we're scrolling it UP!                              
                var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $self.data('speed')); // If this element has a Y offset then add it on
                if ($self.data('offsetY'))
                {
                    yPos += $self.data('offsetY');
                } // Put together our final background position
                var coords = '50% ' + yPos + 'px'; // Move the background
                $self.css(
                {
                    backgroundPosition: coords
                }); // Check for other sprites in this section  
                $('[data-type="sprite"]', $self).each(function()
                { // Cache the sprite
                    var $sprite = $(this); // Use the same calculation to work out how far to scroll the sprite
                    var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $sprite.data('speed'));
                    var coords = $sprite.data('Xposition') + ' ' + (yPos + $sprite.data('offsetY')) + 'px';
                    $sprite.css(
                    {
                        backgroundPosition: coords
                    });
                }); // sprites
                // Check for any Videos that need scrolling
                $('[data-type="video"]', $self).each(function()
                { // Cache the video
                    var $video = $(this); // There's some repetition going on here, so 
                    // feel free to tidy this section up. 
                    var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $video.data('speed'));
                    var coords = (yPos + $video.data('offsetY')) + 'px';
                    $video.css(
                    {
                        top: coords
                    });
                }); // video    
            } // in view
        }); // window scroll
    }); // each data-type
}); // document ready
```

**Concerns:**

1. jQuery might be to bloated for what I intended to do. Can this still be simplified and optimized?
2. Improper use of HTML tags
3. Code (animation) are running without the other elements fully loaded yet.

This is still being develop, I'd appreciate to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, if you're trying to do these animations sequentially, the code isn't written to do that.  You need to pass a function reference, not the result of a function call so this:

```
function introIconFirst()
{
    $('h2.ribbon').css(
    {
        'marginTop': '+30px',
        'opacity': '0'
    }).animate(
    {
        marginTop: '0',
        opacity: '1'
    }, 1500, 'easeOutElastic', introIconSecond());
}
```

should be this:

```
function introIconFirst()
{
    $('h2.ribbon').css(
    {
        'marginTop': '+30px',
        'opacity': '0'
    }).animate(
    {
        marginTop: '0',
        opacity: '1'
    }, 1500, 'easeOutElastic', introIconSecond);   // <== change made to pass only function reference here
}
```

and likewise, fix the other ones that have the same issue.

Other issues I see:

1. You're doing a 200ms interval on a 400ms animation or a 200ms interval on a 700ms animation.  That sounds like you're asking for trouble and won't visually get what you want with two/three animations competing at the same time.
2. You probably don't want to be recalculating the selectors every time your setInterval gets called as that's a lot of wasted CPU multiple times per second.  Calculate them once before you start the setInterval and use that result.
3. `.detach()` should be changed to `.remove()` in this code as `.detach()` should only be used if you're saving a reference to the removed items and reusing them later.  Otherwise, `.remove()` does a better job cleaning up jQuery stuff and I assume you probably want to only clean up the item you are no longer hovering over:

Change to `.remove()` here:

```
$(".options li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).append('<span class="elem1"></span><span class="elem2"></span>');
  },
  function () {
    $(this).find("span").remove();
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your review. 

Honestly, I'm still confused how to use setInterval properly. Im confused because I animated it by interval and I also animate it using animate(). 

I tried making the interval the same as the animation's (animation()) milliseconds and it caused delayed every time I hover.

Thank You!

Comment: @Pennf0lio - If you want it to start right away, you call the animation directly the first time and then you call it the subsequent times with `setInterval()`.